# how to ignore action on printing a field value using awk

Tags: awk, fasta

Hello I have several files whose starting line (or record) follows this format:

```
cat file_1.txt | grep '>'
> CP022114.1 Kluyvera georgiana strain YDC799 chromosome, complete genome
```

I want to retrieve the second field on that record which corresponds to the genus taxonomic category, on this example it is "Kluyvera". So I use this:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $2}' file.txt
```

and I got

```
Kluyvera
```

The issue is that in some files the second field doesnt corresponds to the genus taxonomic category and the genus is preceeded by the string "candidatus":

```
cat file_2.txt | grep '>'
> NTKC01000006.1 Candidatus Thioglobus sp. MED-G25 SUP05-clade-MED-G25-C6, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

on the above record , "Thioglobus" is to the genus of the specie. so when I try the above awk command it retrieves me "Candidatus".

I want awk to print "this file has candidatus" instead of retrieving the second field for that record.

Comment: If your lines start with `>` the second fields of your two examples should be `CP022114.1` and `NTKC01000006.1`, respectively, not `Kluyvera` and `Candidatus`. Did you really try `awk 'NR==1{print $2}'` yourself?

Comment: Probably the OP has one sequence per input file and so in practice `NR==1` is equivalent to `/>/` and the remaining lines are the actual sequence.

Comment: @tripleee As they `grep '>'` to retrieve the target record, I suspect the `>` is part of it. Before I edited the question it was hidden by the markdown rendering but it was there.

Comment: Yes yes, this is part of the FASTA format. It's a simple text format where any line which starts with `>` is a header which starts a new sequence. If they had multiple sequences in the file, `grep '>'` would retrieve more than one.

Comment: OK, but then if they want what they call the genus taxonomic category from this header with a leading `>` field, they should look at fields 3 (or 4), not 2 (or 3), shouldn't they?

Comment: Yeah, those parts are unclear, and I have voted to close for that reason.

Comment: Can `Candidatus` appear anywhere in your file or it is present solely in header line?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have input file like this:

```sh
cat file

CP022114.1 Kluyvera georgiana strain YDC799 chromosome, complete genome
NTKC01000006.1 Candidatus Thioglobus sp. MED-G25 SUP05-clade-MED-G25-C6, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

You can use `awk` like this with a conditional print:

```sh
awk '{print ($2 == "Candidatus" ? $3 : $2)}' file

Kluyvera
Thioglobus
```

Or if you want to print a custom string for the `Candidatus` record then use:

```sh
awk '{print ($2 == "Candidatus" ? "this file has candidatus" : $2)}' file

Kluyvera
this file has candidatus
```

Comment: @Valentin: Did this work out?